# Number of directed multigraphs with $n$ arrows?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

For context, I'm trying to work out the combinatorial properties of constructing a directed multigraph from a fixed number of arrows (with a vertex only existing when an arrow is connected to it).

How many possible directed multigraphs are there (up to isomorphism), given the following conditions?

- There are a set number of edges.
- There are no isolated vertices.
- Edges and vertices are unlabelled.
- There can be loops; that is, edges like $(a,a)$ are allowed in addition to $(a,b)$.
- There can be multiple edges; that is, there can be more than one edge going *from* $a$ *to* $b$.

Another way to think about it is, how many isomorphism classes of multisets (with cardinality $n$) of ordered pairs (of, you could say, vertices) are there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The case where vertices are labeled would be easy to count. The tool that lets us go from labeled to unlabeled vertices is the [Pólya enumeration theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem). (The Wikipedia article gives an example of using this to count undirected graphs with a fixed number of edges, and the directed case is only slightly different.)

I will forget about isolated vertices for now, and allow directed edges $vw$ and $wv$ to coexist. So let's start with the complete directed graph (with $n$ vertices and all $N := n(n-1)$ possible directed edges), and color the edges with two colors: a color that represents "there is an edge" (with weight $1$) and a color that represents "there is no edge" (with weight $0$). The generating function of the set of colors is $f(t) = 1+t$. The weight of a coloring is the total weight of the colors used, so it's the number of edges in our graph; therefore, we want to find the number of colorings with a fixed weight.

We take $G$ to be the group $S_n$ acting on the vertices of the complete directed graph. To apply the Pólya enumeration theorem as in the Wikipedia article, we need to compute $Z_G(t_1, t_2, \dots, t_N)$. So, for each permutation $\sigma$ of the vertices and each $k \in \{1, \dots, N\}$, we need to compute $c_k(\sigma)$, the number of $k$-cycles in the action of $\sigma$ on the set of edges.

For example, let's try this for $n=3$ vertices, with $N = 6$ possible edges. Here, there are $3$ types of permutations:

- The identity permutation fixes all edges, giving a $t_1^6$ term.
- A swap like $(1\;2)$ acts on the set of edges by three $2$-cycles; the edges $12$ and $21$ are swapped, the edges $13$ and $23$ are swapped; the edges $31$ and $32$ are swapped. This gives a $t_2^3$ term, and there are three such permutations.
- A permutation like $(1\;2\;3)$ acts on the set of edges by two $3$-cycles; the edges $12, 23, 31$ are permuted cyclically, and so are the edges $21, 32, 13$. This gives a $t_3^2$ term, and there are two such permutations.

So we get $Z_G(t_1, t_2, t_3, t_4, t_5, t_6) = \frac16(t_1^6 + 3 t_2^3 + 2 t_3^2).$ We might as well make this $Z_G(t_1, t_2, t_3)$ since no longer cycles appear.

By the Pólya enumeration theorem, the generating function of directed graphs on $3$ vertices up to isomorphism is
\begin{align}
   Z_G(1 + t, 1 + t^2, 1 + t^3) &= \frac16((1+t)^6 + 3(1+t^2)^3 + 2(1+t^3)^2) \\
       &= 1 + t + 4 t^2 + 4 t^3 + 4 t^4 + t^5 + t^6
\end{align}
so there are $1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1$ directed graphs on $3$ vertices with $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ edges respectively. Here is a diagram of all these graphs to verify the count:

[image]

You also wanted to rule out isolated vertices, which this doesn't do, but that's easy to fix. Let's say that $a_{n,m}$ is the number of $n$-vertex $m$-edge digraphs without the isolated vertex condition, and $a_{n,m}^*$ is the number that have no isolated vertices. Then we have
$$
   a_{n,m} = a_{0,m}^* + a_{1,m}^* + a_{2,m}^* + \dots + a_{n,m}^*
$$
because the number of $n$-vertex $m$-edge digraphs with $k$ isolated vertices is counted by $a_{n-k,m}^*$. From this, we can get $a_{n,m}^* = a_{n,m} - a_{n-1,m}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was looking for a looser case (about to edit the question to reflect it), allowing loops and also allowing the number of vertices to vary. For the latter part, at least, I can see how this generating function could be used over all possible values of $n$ (vertices) and summed up. Also, the directed multigraph case is what I'm most interested in.

Comment: You can allow loops and multiple edges with minor variation of the problem. For loops, you will just need to modify $Z_G$. For multiple edges, replace $f(t)$ by $1 + t + t^2 + \dots = \frac1{1-t}$. There are many variants of this problem, but all of them are counted in essentially the same way.